# Force mingw32-make to ignore sh

Tags: windows, makefile, mingw

I noticed that, if sh.exe is present in the PATH, then mingw32-make will use it to launch commands. But if it is not, then it will use cmd.exe. The problem is that both application are .... completely incompatible, and there is no way to create makefiles to would work for both.

Is there a way to ask mingw32-make to always use cmd.exe? Or to create an environment forcing mingw32-make to ignore this sh.exe?

Comment: Why do you even have sh.exe on PATH when not running under something like Cygwin or MSYS? That's just terrible.

Comment: @rubenvb Because a lot of applications (such as ... git) add it for themselves. Also, some people add sh.exe on their MinGW installation, but I cannot count on it.

Comment: Git on Windows has an option to only add the `git` command to PATH and leave the rest of the POSIX stuff it uses under the hood out of it. The installer even warns adding everything to PATH might conflict with other Windows utilities. That's user error. Not your concern.

Comment: @rubenvb I need git from the command line, so this is not an option. And anyway, there should be a way to specify if a makefile has been written for cmd.exe or sh.exe as they are not compatible.

Comment: That's why you should pick [this option](http://i.imgur.com/AHcvlx2.png). Note how the option you picked has a big red warning telling you to not pick it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well, if you know how to do it ... for example to erase files you will need to use 'rm' with sh.exe but 'del' with 'cmd.exe' so you need to know which is used.

Comment: @PierreBdR: Which is fine. A simple check of environment variables can switch your commands around

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out, I found the solution by chance. I had read that mingw32-make is supposed to look at the SHELL environment variable ... but it doesn't! However, you can specify the option on the command line like so:

```
mingw32-make SHELL=cmd
```

This is not ideal, but the best I could come up with. For now, I will leave this question un-answered, in case someone comes with a better answer.

Comment: This is the legitimate answer when you need `sh.exe` but also `make` with `cmd.exe`. IMO there's nothing "not ideal" about this.

Comment: Awesome, than you! BTW you also helped a lot of FPGA developers :-): https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Embedded-Development-Tools/SDK-won-t-build-in-WIN7-errors-out/m-p/241584/highlight/false BTW worth noting that SHELL=cmd is case-sensitive, so the switch should be specified exactly like this.

Comment: It also works to add SHELL=cmd in the Makefile itself, before the rules, so you don't have to remember it every invocation.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue, and resolved it by launching the make from a batch file, but before calling the make added:
set PATH... with only the necessary roots.